# XMPP Spring Integration Property or field 'json' cannot be found

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, spring-integration, smack

I tried to implement XMPP with Spring Integration using the following tutorial:
https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-integration/firebase-cloud-messaging-xmpp-server-example-receive-upstream-messages-spring-integration

However I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'json' cannot be found on object of type 'org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.StandardExtensionElement' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:90) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:111) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:328) ~[spring-expression-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.xmpp.inbound.ChatMessageListeningEndpoint$ChatMessagePublishingStanzaListener.processStanza(ChatMessageListeningEndpoint.java:143) ~[spring-integration-xmpp-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]
```

So how to receive an upstream message within Spring integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem that you don't show what is your code on the matter. And looks like you really are missing the fact that the mentioned sample is based on the **GCM**, where `getExtension('google:mobile:data')` from the `org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message` really returns for us a `org.jivesoftware.smackx.gcm.packet.GcmPacketExtension` with the `getJson()` method.

In your case it looks like your get a `org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.StandardExtensionElement`. So, that really is expected do not have a `json` over there.

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan, thanks for your reply. In fact I send upstream Message through Firebase Cloud Messaging from an Android Application. But in org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.StandardExtensionElement I found that instead of getJson() I see that there is a field called text. So I think text is Strin Json. So do you know how to get data from it?

Comment: As I said in my answer: we don't know your code and you don't show what fails for your, but anyway if you follow that sample, then your `payload-expression` must be like this: `payload-expression="getExtension('google:mobile:data').text"`

Comment: Exactly, this solved my problem: `payload-expression="getExtension('google:mobile:data').text"` ..Thanks for your help