# How to send XMPP Message to FCM using Spring Integration

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, xmpp, spring-integration

I am totally new in XMPP and Spring Integration, and want to send message to FCM user. I created an XML configuration for Outbound Message as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
           xmlns:int-xmpp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xmpp"
           ...>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.avantovr.esysync_backend.webservices.restful.fcm.xmppserver" />
  <int-xmpp:outbound-channel-adapter id="xmppOutboundAdapter" channel="xmppOutboundChannel" xmpp-connection="xmppConnection"/>
  <int:service-activator ref="fcmSender" input-channel="xmppOutbound" />
  <int:logging-channel-adapter id="xmppOutboundChannel" log-full-message="true" />
    </beans>
```

Now I want to create a Java Class in which there is method for sending Downstrwam messagr via XMPP to FCM. Pls is there any beginner example for sending and receiving xmpp messages to FCM via Spring integration?

Comment: I have seen some examples in the net but most of them hard to understand or not complete

Comment: Looks like related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160191/xmpp-spring-integration-property-or-field-json-cannot-be-found. Please, fix your language. The English is not my native one and I just don't understand some of your words. I believe I'm not alone here who might complain about inappropriate language. Thanks for understanding. And please, read a Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xmpp.html.There is also a sample on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/xmpp

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but its good enough for me. First time dealing with XMPP.

I dont have any XML configurations other than pom.xml dependencies.

There is a 5 seconds sleep and reconnect after a disconnect. *FCM disconnects XMPP connection from time to time to load balance.*

Sending ACKs back is working, receiveing ACKs and NACKs are not tested.

**To send a message from java -> fcm -> phone;**

```
@Autowired
private XmppConfig xmppConfig;

xmppConfig.getXmppConnection().sendStanza(generateStanza(messageId,json));
```

**json above shoulde be like this, from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server**

```
  {
      "to":"REGISTRATION_ID",  // "to" replaces "registration_ids"
      "message_id":"m-1366082849205" // new required field
      "data":
      {
          "hello":"world",
      }
      "time_to_live":"600",
      "delivery_receipt_requested": true/false
  }
```

**smack dependencies**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-java7</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
        <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
fcm.sender_id=YOUR_SENDER_ID@fcm.googleapis.com
fcm.server_key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY
fcm.host=fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com
fcm.port=5235
```

**XmppConfig.java**

```
import com.alessoft.utils.Utils;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.roster.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jxmpp.stringprep.XmppStringprepException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

@Configuration
class XmppConfig implements ConnectionListener {

    @Value("${fcm.sender_id}")
    private String senderId;
    @Value("${fcm.server_key}")
    private String server_key;
    @Value("${fcm.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${fcm.port}")
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private XmppService xmppService;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmppConfig.class);
    private volatile boolean xmppConnected;
    private XMPPTCPConnection xmppConnection;

    public XMPPTCPConnection getXmppConnection() {
        return xmppConnection;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> prepareXmppConnection()).start();
    }

    public XMPPConnection prepareXmppConnection() {
        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = null;
        try {
            conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setHost(host)
                    .setPort(port)
                    .setSendPresence(false)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                    .setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault())
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(senderId, server_key)
                    .setXmppDomain("somedomain.com")
                    .build();
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            logger.info("prepareXmppConnection error", e);
        }
        xmppConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);
        xmppConnection.addAsyncStanzaListener(xmppService, xmppService);
        xmppConnection.addConnectionListener(this);
        Roster.getInstanceFor(xmppConnection).setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);
        establishXmppConnection();
        return xmppConnection;
    }

    private void establishXmppConnection() {
        try {
            xmppConnection.connect();
            xmppConnection.login();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("XMPP establishXmppConnection error", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
        logger.info("LOST CONNECTION TO FCM XMPP ON ERROR", e);
        Utils.sleep(5000);
        establishXmppConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        logger.info("LOST CONNECTION TO FCM XMPP");
        Utils.sleep(5000);
        establishXmppConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {
        logger.info("CONNECTED TO FCM XMPP");
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
        logger.info("AUTHENTICATED TO FCM XMPP");
    }

}
```

**XmppService.java**

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.StanzaListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.StanzaFilter;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Stanza;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.util.PacketParserUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class XmppService implements StanzaListener, StanzaFilter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmppService.class);
    @Autowired
    private XmppConfig xmppConfig;

    @Override
    public void processStanza(Stanza stanzaXml) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException, InterruptedException, SmackException.NotLoggedInException {
        JSONObject stanza = XML.toJSONObject(stanzaXml.toXML(null).toString());
        if (!stanza.has("message")) return;
        JSONObject message = stanza.getJSONObject("message");

        if (message.has("type")) {
            normalMessage(message);
        } else {
            otherMessage(message);
        }
    }

    private void otherMessage(JSONObject message) {
        JSONObject gcm = message.getJSONObject("gcm");
        String contentString = gcm.getString("content");
        JSONObject content = new JSONObject(contentString);
        if (content.getString("message_type").equals("ack")) {
            logger.info("RECEIVED ACK");
        } else if (content.getString("message_type").equals("nack")) {
            logger.info("RECEIVED NACK: \n" + content.toString(2));
        } else {
            logger.info("RECEIVED UNKNOWN: \n" + content.toString());
        }

    }

    private void normalMessage(JSONObject message) {
        JSONObject gcm = message.getJSONObject("gcm");
        String contentString = gcm.getString("content");
        JSONObject content = new JSONObject(contentString);
        String message_id = content.getString("message_id");
        String from = content.getString("from");
        if (content.has("message_type")) {
            logger.info("NOT FROM DEVICE:\n" + message.toString());
        } else {
            processMessage(content);
            sendAck(message_id, from);
        }
    }

    private void processMessage(JSONObject content) {
        // your own processing
    }


    private void sendAck(String message_id, String regId) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("to", regId);
            json.put("message_id", message_id);
            json.put("message_type", "ack");
            String messageString = String.format("<message><gcm xmlns=\"google:mobile:data\">%s</gcm></message>", json.toString());
            Stanza stanza = PacketParserUtils.parseStanza(messageString);
            xmppConfig.getXmppConnection().sendStanza(stanza);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("fcm sending ack error", e);
        }
    }

    private Stanza generateStanza(String messageId, JSONObject json) {
        String messageString = String.format("<message id=\"%s\"><gcm xmlns=\"google:mobile:data\">%s</gcm></message>", messageId, json.toString());
        try {
            return PacketParserUtils.parseStanza(messageString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("generateStanza error", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Stanza stanza) {
        return true;
    }
}
```